# Bringing spare horses when you have to "ride hard?"

Tags: fantasy-genre, trope

How does this trope make any sense? I've been re-reading the Sword of Truth series, and numerous times they mention that they need "6 horses. We're going to ride hard and need the spares." How does this work exactly? Aren't the other horses just as tired? Wouldn't it make more sense to ride hard on one set, stop in a town and get more?

Comment: I'd imagine that they'd certainly be tired, but probably not as tired as the ones carrying an extra 200+ pounds of passengers/supplies.

Comment: I'd thought about that, too. But in some cases, it's my understanding that the spares carry the extra gear and such. That way the main horse can last a bit longer. If the weight is so evenly distributed, then I'm not sure how this is possible.

Comment: Does horse endurance count as a "question seeking scientific solutions or explanations"?  I'm a bit dubious about this one but I've given it a VTC for that reason and we'll see what the community decides...

Comment: @DarthMelkor: It's possible. But this is a common trope in the fantasy genre, and thus should still be on topic.

Comment: @MyCodeSucks - agreed; I'm really uncertain about it overall.

Comment: It's a viable question, just a challenging one. Just because no one WANTS to answer it doesn't mean it shouldn't get one. The Sword of Truth novels are one writer's attempt to redefine fantasy fiction with a bit more reality or at least structure to the fantastic. His addition of the multiple horse idea has a basis in FACT.

Comment: @Thaddeus: I'd be quite hesitant to describe a series that starts out blatantly ripping off the epic fantasy *The Wheel of Time* and gradually transitions to blatantly ripping off the epically paranoid delusions of Ayn Rand as having "a basis in fact" pretty much anywhere!

Comment: @MasonWheeler: LOL, by that logic, _Wheel of Time_ ripped off _Sword of Shannara_. And _Sword of Shannara_ ripped off _Lord of the Rings_.

Comment: Talking about the horse FACTS not the crazed socio-political perspectives.

Comment: @MyCodeSucks: Admittedly it's been a while since I read *Sword of Shanarra*, but I don't quite see what sort of obvious parallels exist between it and *The Wheel of Time.*  Whereas anyone who's read the first few *Sword of Truth* books, and the *Wheel of Time* books that were published at around the same time, can clearly see that Goodkind "created" his work by throwing the plot of *The Wheel of Time* in a blender and mixing in a few cups of Grimdark Sauce.  (A rather distasteful formula that, sadly, was later used quite successfully by such notables as Peter Brett and Christopher Nolan...)

Comment: @MasonWheeler: It's the obvious parallel ALL fantasy books have: random nobody discovers they have a destiny to be a hero or save the world.

Comment: @MyCodeSucks: "ALL fantasy books"?  Dude, you *seriously* need to broaden your horizons.  I'd recommend the *Kingkiller Chronicles* by Pat Rothfuss (wandering scholar chronicling the autobiography of a random nobody who used to be considered a hero but ended up somehow screwing up the world pretty badly) and anything at all from Brandon Sanderson, but especially *Elantris* and *Warbreaker*, (the latter of which can be downloaded free from his site, and is about a really interesting twist on an arranged marriage, and trying to stop a devastating war from breaking out), just for starters...

Comment: @MasonWheeler: Okay, maybe not ALL, but most. You get my point. Side note, _Elantris_ is in my queue of audio books. :D

Comment: @MyCodeSucks: It is [a fairly common trope,](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TheChosenOne) I'll grant you that.  But there's plenty of really good fantasy literature (and fantasy in other media formats) out there that doesn't use it at all.  And if I were you, I'd seriously consider moving *Elantris* to the front of the queue.  Sanderson is that good.

Comment: @MasonWheeler It's a fairly common trope indeed but, like you pointed out, some authors deliberately set out to subvert it. Like for example Moorcock: Elric is not a random nobody, but a powerful sorcerer and ruler of the most powerful nation in his world; his goals rarely are as simple as "saving the world"; he tends to inadvertently cause the death of his friends; his actions end up *destroying* the world :)

Comment: I don't mind this question being about the physical capabilities of animals, but I *do* mind if it's being too-broad in its scope. If limited to the one canon (Sword of Truth) only, then I'm happy with it to be re-opened.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### In the Sword of Truth novels, I believe the goal of having multiple horses was to allow for better distribution of weight, meaning strong and well-conditioned horses could probably double the distance a human could travel in a day without becoming too worn out, if cared for properly at night.

- This probably meant they traveled through regions where water was easily available since carrying water would significantly reduce the distance able to be traveled.
- Multiple horses offered redundancy in case of accident, and if things really hit the fan, meat to eat, or a relatively rested horse to try and bolt away from an enemy leaving a valuable commodity behind as a distraction.

#### Making the Case:

**While the trope of multiple horses may be used in fantasy fiction, there are other [tropes around horses written into fiction](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/EquineAndEquestrianTropes) that are far more prevalent and this may explain why the idea of multiple horses was chosen by the Sword of Truth series as a means of "moving quickly."**

- History and fantasy writing make for difficult research conditions. In fantasy and fiction, horses are often larger than life, far more durable, travel much further at greater speeds, exist without food or care for weeks and survive conditions that in real life would and should equal maiming or death for them.
- There are many, many tropes regarding horses in fantasy fiction. So many, in fact, TVtropes has an entire selection of them. (Worth perusing if you plan on writing any fantasy fiction with horses.)
- I believe the goal of multiple horses is a laudable goal given how horses are treated in most fantasy fiction. If your goal is to portray horses relatively realistically, you would want to have multiple horses traveling if:

  - You had sufficient water, food and/or grazing opportunity to maintain the horse's energy requirements. If the land is bountiful and you were able to carry enough supplementary high energy foods, multiple horses could distribute the weight of both food and gear far better than one horse could.
  - Unless you were breeding horses for weight-bearing, or had a culture where horses were part of the lifestyle of the people (See: Mongols or **[Mongolian horse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mongolian_horse)**) it is difficult to find horses who can both carry large riders and great weights, and still expect them to travel great distances.

**[Mongolian Horsemen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mongol_military_tactics_and_organization) and their horses had a near symbiotic relationship:**

> - First, their horses were small, scrappy, could live off of air (practically) and were very agile.  Therefore, these formidable but light horses could carry them into battle and then retreat quickly and stealthily into the surrounding woods.  If needed, they could travel for miles…  And, the Mongols had the breeding business down pat. They had huge numbers of these well trained and well bred horses.  By culling the best warhorses for reproduction, the Mongols had a superior cavalry.
> - Second, they didn’t ride them for 50 miles a day… they rode 4 different horses for 50 miles a day.  You see, what they did was each warrior had 2-4 horses.  He would armor one and ride it for a while, then switch.  In this way, the unarmored horses just ran along and were fairly fresh.

[image]

- Both the Mongols and the **[Pony Express](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pony_Express)** riders were considered small by modern comparisons. Pony Express riders were expected to weigh about 125 pounds.

> - **In 1860, there were about 157 Pony Express stations that were about 10 miles (16 km) apart along the Pony Express route. This was roughly the distance a horse could travel at a gallop before tiring.** At each station stop the express rider would change to a fresh horse, taking only the mail pouch called a mochila (from the Spanish for pouch or backpack) with him.
> - The mochila could hold 20 pounds (9 kg) of mail along with the 20 pounds (9 kg) of material carried on the horse. Included in that 20 pounds (9 kg) were a water sack, a Bible, a horn for alerting the relay station master to prepare the next horse, and a revolver.[15] Eventually, everything except one revolver and a water sack was removed, allowing for a total of 165 pounds (75 kg) on the horse's back. **Riders, who could not weigh over 125 pounds (57 kg), changed about every 75–100 miles (120–160 km), and rode day and night.** In emergencies, a given rider might ride two stages back to back, over 20 hours on a quickly moving horse.

- Fantasy writers tend to create super-horses which can move great distances, carry fantastic weights and live on a raisin and a glass of water. But real horses can't do that without significant training, breeding and conditioning and they generally require great care, skilled ridership and a great deal of knowledge regarding horses.
- A human traveling by foot and by horse will have cover similar distances (about 20-25 miles per day) if you are trying to take care of the horse. The benefit of riding a horse, however, is the rider is less tired and can still maintain some physical activity after a day's travel (where he would be far less effective if he walked that entire distance himself.)

  - In real life, horses are not nearly as indestructible as modern media would make them out to be. If you were traveling in a life or death mission and you wanted to be sure to get there and started out with the opportunity to have more than one horse, you would, because horses can: throw a shoe, break a leg, develop colic, become temperamental, get attacked, get wounded, etc. More horses, means a better shot at getting where you need to be.

**For those of you thinking temperamental? How dangerous can that be? TVTropes points out in their section called [Horsing Around](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/HorsingAround), just HOW dangerous, starting with this quote:**

> *"Riding is the only thing a King learns how to do right, since a horse
>   is no courtier and will just as soon throw a Prince as a stable boy."*
>
> - [Truth in Television](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TruthInTelevision) since horses are still animals. Very big, powerful animals. Aside from the obvious danger of a kick or a nasty bite (which can be severe enough to disable or even kill) some horses can have a nasty habit of lying down suddenly when you're riding them... to roll in the grass while you're still on them. The results can be fatal. So if your horse goes down suddenly... get off the horse IMMEDIATELY! (especially if he's in water.) They can also spook or bolt if they're stung or startled, leaping or galloping off in a panic. When that happens getting dumped is almost inevitable.

[image]

Comment: Detailed, thorough answer. I like the pointing out that authors tend to essentially "super hero" the horses.